# how to rewrite a dataframe with same set number of value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to rewrite the front table to the later one, the first one has one same set of value,how to transform it to the second one in pandas?
[first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDE4r.png)

[second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmugH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in pandas, use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'place': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c'],
                   'age': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'number': [13, 32, 21, 5, 34, 123, 3, 434, 678, 65, 234, 23, 65, 43, 32]})
result = df.pivot(index='place', columns='age', values='number')
print(result)
```

The result will be like this:

```
age      0   1    2    3   4
place                       
a       13  32   21    5  34
b      123   3  434  678  65
c      234  23   65   43  32
```

And if you need to read/write data from/to excel, use: [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter)

Comment: Thx a lot for the pivot_table,what if there's a column 'Alias' which have the same value for same 'place'  like 'aa' for 'a' 'bb' for 'b' , 'cc' for 'c'. how can I add it to the result dataframe?

Comment: If it is in the initial table, you can use: result = df.pivot_table(index=['place', 'Alias'], columns='age', values='number')